# Pycharm virtual environment only displays html of my project, no CSS

Tags: css, django, pycharm, static-files

I've managed to set up a virtual environment in Pycharm in order to edit my Django app, and the associated website that it interacts with.

The interpreter recognizes Django, and I can make edits to my app, but for some reason it can't seem to find my css files that are in my 'static_files' directory.

Here are the instructions in my settings.py file, which Django should be able to access:`STATIC_URL = '/static/' STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_files')`

[Here are my directories in my project, maybe something is in the wrong place?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2s8rh.png)

I've tried adding STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_files'),], and still nothing changes, can't find CSS.

Not sure what to do about this, Pycharm seems to run into consistently run into problems that don't exist on my regular server for hosting my site and app.

Edit: here are some screenshots to show the specific problem I am having and how pycharm is reporting it.

[These are all the messages my terminal reports when I run my server. Notably, I receive a 404 error when pycharm tries to retrieve my styles3.css file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o32yt.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am writing here because  I can't write comments.  If pycharm just doesn't see the directory, then right-click on it and click "mark directory as" and select the item you want.  If I understood the question correctly

Comment: Which option do I select? I don't know what any of the options mean. When I right-click on my static-files directory, which contains my css directory, I get "Sources Root", "Excluded", "Test Sources Root" and "Namespace Package". I do not know what any of these do, or if I should be marking my "css" directory instead. Can you explain a little bit more in-depth?

Comment: @pythonanus Do you have a problem that css files don't work and django throws an error, or that specifically pycharm doesn't see css files in the static folder?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I edited my answer to include a screenshot of my pycharm terminal. I'm not sure how I would know the difference between pycharm not being able to find my css files, or what it would look like if django was the one unable to find them. I also know that that migration message won't affect anything. I was having the same issues before I added a migration.

Comment: @pythonanus, see your problem in django. You have a static error 404, i.e. the page was not found